# ActiveAdmin Disable Checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, activeadmin

I'd like to check if my table contains a particular value and if so, set the checkbox to disabled.

I've also tried disabling the checkbox like so, however can't seem to get it to work.

In /admin/ file:

`form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Form' do
      f.input :checkbox, :disabled => true
    end
    f.actions
  end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the syntax is slightly different. Try this:

```
 f.input :checkbox, :input_html => { :disabled => true }
```

Activeadmin uses [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), so you can refer to their docs.